# Google Slides API activating script on click of element

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I am trying to create a branching scenario using google slides, the idea is that someone viewing [the presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1z76k0CBJkfDLAogfE0g2-bjtHU-GMG58I_BOdnICdVQ) can click on the buttons and see the outcome of their selections.

The first few slides it's easy, it's a 1 to 1 so I can just use the "link" feature in slides.

The tricky part is once you progress to slide 3. I want the slide they are directed to by clicking on the "course of action" options to be based on all the currently selected options.

So here is where I'm stuck - I need to figure out how to have an interaction (click) with the slide in presentation mode trigger a script.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this in Google Slides?

Comment: ! ! ! ! ! ! ! See - Star - Comment in Issue tracker! ! ! ! ! ! !    
"Page elements on Slides should be selectable to run scripts like the shapes and images in spreadsheet"   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186214943

"Presentation mode in slides should fill window not device"  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186204484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the Slides Service for Google Apps Script and the Google Slides REST API don't include a way to call a script on a click of an element. This feature is only included on Google Sheets ([Clickable images and drawings in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets))

NOTE: The Google's official documentation very rarely includes a page about missing features. It could be possible that someone already submitted a feature request through the [official Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191640%2B). If so, you could star that issue to get notifications about changes on it. Another place to monitor is the [G Suite Developers Blog](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/) and the [Google Apps Script release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/).

Comment: Thanks for that (sorry it took so long for me to respond). I was afraid that would be the case. *sigh* back to the drawing board.

Comment: @Ruben - Is there a link/resource to substantiate the assertion that ONLY Sheets allows such interactions?  I ask because I am interested in this too and it would be nice to know where to get/monitor that information in the event it changes.

Comment: @t.j. The official documentation very rarely includes a page about missing features. It could be possible that someone already submitted a feature request through the official Issue Tracker. If so, you could star that issue to get notifications about changes on it. Another place to monitor is the G Suite Developers Blog and the Google Apps Script release notes.

Comment: @Rubén - Fair enough, I figured it didnt hurt to ask.  Thanks!

Comment: @t.j. I just added my above comment + links to the referred resources to the answer.

Comment: ! ! ! ! ! ! ! See - Star - Comment in Issue tracker! ! ! ! ! ! !    
"Page elements on Slides should be selectable to run scripts like the shapes and images in spreadsheet"   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186214943

"Presentation mode in slides should fill window not device"  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186204484