# How to call a function via a link/button on a Google Slide?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, google-slides

I want to be able to send a formatted email by clicking a link/button on a Google Slide. An example scenario would be sending a feedback form to all staff after a  meeting, with the link on the very last slide.

I already have the code for the email in Google Script and it works perfectly fine when I run it (I also have an HTML file for the format), but I cannot find a way to run it via a link/button on a slide.

I would rather not run it every time the slide is open, only when a special link/button is clicked. Is there a way in Google Script where I can do this in Slides? Any help, method, suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Edit: The sidebar solution works for me! Can't believe I didn't think of it before but thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Slides API activating script on click of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47919495/google-slides-api-activating-script-on-click-of-element)

Comment: You could put your button on a sidebar.

Comment: ! ! ! ! ! ! ! See - Star - Comment in Issue tracker! ! ! ! ! ! !    
"Page elements on Slides should be selectable to run scripts like the shapes and images in spreadsheet"   https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186214943

"Presentation mode in slides should fill window not device"  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/186204484

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done anything with slides for a while but I just built this using a simple side bar interface.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides=ss.getSlides();
  var html='<input type="button" value="Run Server Side Function" onClick="clickMe();" />';
  html+='<script>function clickMe(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function (time) { alert("You clicked me at " + time + ".");}).getSomeData();}</script>';
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}


function getSomeData() {
  return Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")
}
```

Of course, it's a bit easier to write more complex code using an html file but this was just a quick little demo script.

Here's what my little sidebar and button look like:

[image]

Apparently, the side bar does not show up during the presentation.  Oh well, sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google Slides does not support clickable objects/images yet. You can check the google documentation and the only to do that is using Google Sheets:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

Note: Google's official documentation is a mess in my opinion, but I tried here some approaches and did not have success.