# How do I create a Multiple-Choice-Quiz within Google Slides

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api, multiple-choice, google-slides

I want to make a Multiple-Choice-Quiz at the end of my presentation. I neither have experience with the Apps Script nor with the Slides API. I want to select specific text elements and let them listen for a click on them and change their color to red or green, depending on if the answer is right.

I made a small example to show how I want it a bit to look and work like:

```js
//sorry for this long code but I had to do it very quickly

var rightAnswer = document.getElementById("rightAnswer");
var wrongAnswer1 = document.getElementById("wrongAnswer1");
var wrongAnswer2 = document.getElementById("wrongAnswer2");
var wrongAnswer3 = document.getElementById("wrongAnswer3");

document.getElementById("rightAnswer").addEventListener("click", giveRightAnswer);
function giveRightAnswer(){
  rightAnswer.style.color = "green";
  wrongAnswer1.style.color = "red";
  wrongAnswer2.style.color = "red";
  wrongAnswer3.style.color = "red";
  //answer is right/wrong
}
document.getElementById("wrongAnswer1").addEventListener("click", giveRightAnswer);
document.getElementById("wrongAnswer2").addEventListener("click", giveRightAnswer);
document.getElementById("wrongAnswer3").addEventListener("click", giveRightAnswer);
```

```css
li {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 165px;
  margin: 5px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Multiple Choice Quiz Demo</h1>
<h3>Who created Minecraft?</h3>
<ul>
  <li class="wrongAnswers" id="wrongAnswer1">Steve Jobs</li>
  <li class="wrongAnswers" id="wrongAnswer2">Elon Musk</li>
  <li class="wrongAnswers" id="wrongAnswer3">Spongebob</li>
  <li class="wrongAnswers" id="rightAnswer">Markus Notch Persson</li>
</ul>
<p>Click on an answer to get the solution</p>
<p id="answer"></p>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a function via a link/button on a Google Slide?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366657/how-to-call-a-function-via-a-link-button-on-a-google-slide)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately an element of a Slide cannot be attached to a script, the way images and shapes of a Sheet [can fire scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets). So there is no way to achieve this kind of interaction in Google Slides.

As a workaround, you could use Links to achieve a functionality that reminds of a Multiple Choice Quiz, even if it's not exactly what you want. The idea would be to navigate to different slides depending on which option the user clicks by attaching certain elements to certain slides (to attach a link to an element, click the element, go to `Insert > Link`, click `Slides in this presentation` and select the desired slide).

For example, you have a slide with a multiple choice question. Possible answers are `Option A`, `Option B` and `Option C`. If `Option A` is clicked, you navigate to another slide that is basically the same as previous one but with `Option A` turned green. If options B or C are clicked, you navigate to another slide with the clicked option turned red.

In any case, I'd recommend using [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms) for this. Slides is not really the appropriate tool to have a quiz.